# Recursion in js setTimeout how it work? and why it work?

Tags: javascript, recursion

```
function printNumbers(from, to) {
  let current = from;

  function go() {
    alert(current);
    if (current < to) {
      setTimeOut(go, 1000); //recursion to function go() 
    }
    current++; // because of recursion execution should not reach this point 
  }, 1000);
}

printNumbers(5, 10);
```

Please explain to me why ^current++^ works immediately? but because of recursion it should not work. isnt it? please explain me who understand how it work and why

Comment: `setTimeOut` isn't a method.  `setTimeout` is.  And even fixing that typo, `setTimeout` creates an asynchronous branching in logic.  It will not prevent the `current++` from happening until it finishes.

Comment: @Taplar Why won't you just edit?

Comment: Edit what?  I'm explaining a misunderstanding of their assumptions, and pointing out a typo.  Typos are closable reasons.  And explaining a misunderstanding, while helpful, may not solve their actual problem, and thus, is not an answer.

Comment: It is not the responsibility of moderators to edit question to correct typos **in logic**.  The typo may be the entire issue of the question, and in doing so, obscures the issue from future readers.  Fixing typos in logic should be left up to the OP

Comment: @Taplar, I don't want to get into an edit war, but... the typo clearly is not the source of OP's confusion, or he would be encountering something like `Uncaught ReferenceError: setTimeOut is not defined`. But OP does not post this, his question is about the "recursive" passing of `go` to `setTimeout`. The typo is just noise and we should just correct it, no?

Comment: No, it is at the OPs discression to fix typos in logic.  You can make assumptions, but you do not know if they are accurate.  Fixing typos in non-logic in a question *improves* the quality of the question.  Fixing typos in the logic in a question **changes the question**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To supplement Quentin's answer, this `setTimeout(go, 1000)` line (FYI, `setTimeout` is the proper spelling, not `setTimeOut`) isn't actually doing any recursion. It's passing off a function `go` to be called after 1000 ms in the [event loop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) after the stack empties (the same stack that can do recursion and overflow). It's incidental that this all happens within the same function that's passed as a parameter to the timeout which makes it visually look recursive.

What happens is the `setTimeout` line runs and adds the function `go` to the event loop and guarantees a delay of at least 1000 ms. Then, the rest of the synchronous code runs, including the rest of `go` and `current++;`. Later on, when the stack is empty, tasks on the loop are executed in order, including `go` (assuming the 1000 ms timer has elapsed).

This explains why code like:

```
(function run() {
  requestAnimationFrame(run);
  // do stuff
})();
```

never overflows the stack: *it's not actually recursion* and each call frame is destroyed before the next call happens.

As an aside, it may be surprising that

```
(function run() {
  requestAnimationFrame(run);
  // do stuff
})();
```

and

```
(function run() {
  // do stuff
  requestAnimationFrame(run);
})();
```

behave pretty much the same. The reason is that the next `run` callback is guaranteed to execute once all synchronous code (the current call to `run` and anything else on the call stack) completes execution, so it's not like the location causes a block in synchronous execution and the child call gets to do work as would be the case with recursion.

Answer (score 4):

`setTimeout` is not blocking. It puts a function on a queue to be called when some time has passed. The rest of the function still executes without pause.

There is no `return` statement or anything else that would stop the JS engine from reaching the `current++;` statement.